# Avoid repeated null validation in subclass due to CA1062

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

A common inheritance pattern:

```cs
public abstract class Parent
{
  public void Foo(string s)
  {
    _ = s ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));    //null guard
    DoOtherStuff();
    FooImpl(s);                                             //forward to child class
  }
  protected virtual void FooImpl(string s);
}

public class Child : Parent
{
  protected override void FooImpl(string s)
  {
    var l = s.Length;                                      //CA1062
  }
}
```

That gives `CA1062`:

> In externally visible method, validate parameter 's' is non-null before using it.

It has already been validated as non-null.

Is there an NRT attribute or trick I can use to avoid repeated validation? I could use `s!` but I hope there's a better way.

Comment: If you deal with C# >=8.0, set Nullable=enalble property in your project and change signature to `Foo(string?)`.

Comment: There is the NotNull attributre that you can add to the string argument of your base class constructor. It declares a post condition that the value is not null if the method returns. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63389) might be of interest. It seems the analyser generating CA1062 does this by design. Various options are discussed within.

Comment: @Nikerboker Thanks, that is an option in many cases, but here it makes the API surface unnecessarily "dirty" given that the arg is already validated.

Comment: @SeeDee Thanks, tried that but the attribute isn't respected in the child class (when placed on the parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comment by @CharlesMager above, [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63389) repo issue describes the underlying problem.

The summary is `CA1062` is not "NRT aware", so this warning cannot be avoided using NRT tricks.

Won't work because ignored by CA1062:

- `s!`

Works:

- suppress warning, e.g. via `pragma`
- use `[NotNull]` in child class signature
- re-validate parameter
- live with it